# Parent backlog item into a Sprint

Tags: tfs-workitem

When I create multiple product backlog items linked to each other ( parent and child ) – then further I am not able to add Parent backlog item into a Sprint .  Is there a way to add both parent and child PBI in Sprint  the way they get displayed in Backlog items

Comment: Any further information on what do you mean by "I am not able to add Parent backlog item into a Sprint"? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to put one backlog item into one specific Sprint via setting the Iteration. For example, the following screenshot shows that the "PBI Parent" work item is put into Sprint 1.

[image]